# How make model id insertable and editable in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, model

**I can't initialize or edit model id.**

> This is my model and each value has a specific id. For example id = 11 has value "computer" but i can't initialize my model id. When i post id =11 and value ="computer" database set value 1 for id and increments it for next values.

```
  public class Faculty
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

> Database table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Faculty] (
    [Id]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [value] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Faculty] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

> How should i change my model to make my model id insertable?

Comment: Identity on column ID is problem. You need to remove identity

Comment: @ISHIDA I don't want to change table SQL defenition I want change it from my model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the table and re-create it.

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sexes] ( [Id] INT NOT NULL,
[value] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Sexes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);`

If you want your EF to update the id you can do some thing like this

```
`using (var dataContext = new DataModelContainer())
using (var transaction = dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
var user = new User()
{
ID = id,
Name = "John"
};
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] OFF");
dataContext.User.Add(user);
dataContext.SaveChanges();
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] ON");
transaction.Commit();
}`
```

If you want to use dataannotation on model try this -

```
public class MyEntity {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: The problem is not about SQL it is about entity framework ORM.

Comment: I have updated my answer from your model you might need to turn off the identity and save the record and turn back on.

Comment: Your answer seems good but is there any DataAnnotations for my model id field to set identity false?

Comment: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]